# Render Jinja2 Template to string with layout

Tags: python, jinja2

Is it possible to return jinja2 template to string with layout also from string ? 
I know it's possible like this :

```
from jinja2 import Template

html = "{{var}}"
t = Template(html)
print t.render(var="X")
```

but I need to use jinja template extending like this

```
layout = "HEY {%block content%}{%endblock%}"
html = "{%block content%}{{var1}}{%endblock%}"
t = Template(html, layout=layout)
```

Of course layout=layout doesn't work - this is what I'm looking for

thanks

Comment: Perhaps dig into The functions of the `Flask` module. I'm sure there would be plenty of usage examples as it uses it for the template engine. I know in Flask you can render a text string as a template. If you think about it, what's the difference between a string and text in a HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending is handled by loaders rather than templates, so you need a loader. How about something like this?

```
from jinja2 import DictLoader, Environment, Template

def render_with_layout(template_string, layout, **kwargs):
    loader = DictLoader({
        'layout': layout,  # wrap in Template() if necessary
        'template': Template('{% extends "layout" %}' + template_string),
    })
    env = Environment(loader=loader)
    return env.get_template('template').render(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Sweet! In my case i removed Template wrapper from template field in loader and it worked like a charm. Thanks !